# Refresh whole composite/view on mouse click

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am new to swt. In an eclipse plugin, i have created the view which contains some code as shown below.

```
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {

Composite outer = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    outer.setBackground(new Color(null, 207, 255, 206)); // Green

    FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
    formLayout.marginHeight = 5;
    formLayout.marginWidth = 5;
    formLayout.spacing = 5;
    outer.setLayout(formLayout);
    //TOP
    Composite Top = new Composite(outer, SWT.BORDER);
    Top.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    Top.setBackground(new Color(null, 232, 223, 255)); // Blue

    FormData fData = new FormData();
    fData.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fData.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    fData.right = new FormAttachment(100); // Locks on 10% of the view
    fData.bottom = new FormAttachment(20);
    Top.setLayoutData(fData);

    //BOTTOM
    Composite Bottom = new Composite(outer, SWT.BORDER);
    Bottom.setLayout(fillLayout);
    Bottom.setBackground(new Color(null, 255, 235, 223)); // Orange

    fData = new FormData();
    fData.top = new FormAttachment(20);
    fData.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    fData.right = new FormAttachment(100);
    fData.bottom = new FormAttachment(100);
    Bottom.setLayoutData(fData);
```

The Bottom Composite contains some label where on mouseDown of MouseListener the whole page should be redraw. I used dispose but the page is empty but its not creating again. How to redraw or refresh the main parent.

The label code is as shown:

```
    Label label = new Label(Bottom, SWT.NONE);
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {
             for (Control kid : parent.getChildren()) {
                      kid.dispose();
                    }

            //Need to create/redraw th layout here
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use `redraw()` to redraw controls. But it is likely not what you want. Apart form rare edge cases there is no need to explicitly redraw a control. It updates its appearance whenever you change a relevant rproperty like `text`, `foreground`, `brackground`, etc. Why would you want to redraw controls?

Answer (score 0):

Call layout() method on the parent Composite